# What's Int.MaxValue between friends?

Tags: scala, jvm, language-design

The max values of int, float and long in Scala are:

> Int.MaxValue = 2147483647
>
> Float.MaxValue = 3.4028235E38
>
> Long.MaxValue = 9223372036854775807L

From the authors of Scala compiler, [Keynote, PNW Scala 2013](https://www.slideshare.net/extempore/keynote-pnw-scala-2013), slide 16 `What's Int.MaxValue between friends?`:

```
val x1: Float = Long.MaxValue
val x2: Float = Long.MaxValue - Int.MaxValue
println (x1 == x2)

// NO WONDER NOTHING WORKS
```

Why does this expression return `true`?

Comment: Does that compile? Don't you need an equals after `x2`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get a syntax error instead.

Comment: I found the slide you mentioned. The code you posted is different from the code on the slide. The code on the slide doesn't have the syntax error.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://floating-point-gui.de.

Comment: This isn't really a question about Scala or JVM, every language using standard floating point is going to behave the same (just with different names).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `Float` is a 4-byte floating point value. Meanwhile a `Long` is an 8-byte value and an `Int` is also a 4-byte value. However, the way numbers are stored in 4-byte floating point values means that they have only around 8 digits of precision. Consequently, they do not have the capacity to store even the 4 most significant bytes (around 9-10 digits) of a Long regardless of the value of the least 4 significant bytes (another 9-10 digits).

Consequently, the `Float` representation of the two expressions is the same, because the bits that differ are below the resolution of a `Float`. Hence the two values compare equal.

Comment: Giving +1 for writing an answer that avoided every urge to just answer "floating point arithmetic sucks!"  We all wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

Echoing Mike Allen's answer, but hoping to provide some additional context (would've left this as a comment rather than a separate answer, but SO's reputation feature wouldn't let me).

Integers have a maximum range of values defined as either 0 to 2^n (if it is an unsigned integer) or -2^(n-1) to 2^(n-1) (for signed integers) where n is the number of bits in the underlying implementation (n=32 in this case).  If you wish to represent a number larger than 2^31 with a signed value, you can't use an int. A signed long will work up to 2^63. For anything larger than this, a signed float can go up to roughly 2^127.

One other thing to note is that these resolution issues are only in force when the value stored in the floating point number approaches the max. In this case, the subtraction operation causes a change in true value that is *many* orders of magnitude smaller than the first value. A float would not round off the difference between 100 and 101, but it might round off the difference between 10000000000000000000000000000 and 10000000000000000000000000001.

Same goes for small values. If you cast 0.1 to an integer, you get exactly 0. This is not generally considered a failing of the integer data type.

If you are operating on numbers that are many orders of magnitude different in size, and also not able to tolerate rounding errors, you will need data structures and algorithms that account for inherent limitations of binary data representation. One possible solution would be to use a floating point encoding with fewer bits of exponential, thereby limiting the max value but providing for greater resolution is less significant bits. For greater detail, check out:

- look up the IEEE Standard 754 (which defines the floating point encoding)
- http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html
- https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/